# Ubuntu Apt 1.6.6 with client cert and HTTPS

Tags: apt, repository, certificates, client

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, the connection to my repository using https and client cert authentication is no longer working.
My config:

```
Acquire::https::example.com {
    Verify-Peer "true";
    Verify-Host "true";

    CaInfo "/opt/CA.crt";

    SslCert "/opt/user.crt";
    SslKey  "/opt/user.key";
};
```

User `_apt` is owner of the file, rights on the key-file is 600

If I run `strace -f apt-get update`, I see that apt is not trying to open de SSLcert/SSLkey files.

Everything with apt versions < 1.5. These versions had a separate [`apt-transport-https` packege](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt-transport-https)

On a system with apt version 1.4.8, I do see that the SSLCert/SSLkey files are opened.

Other difference:
In apt 1.6.6:

```
cd /usr/lib/apt/methods:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 170152 jan 25 12:41 http
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 jan 30 14:04 https -> http
```

In apt 1.4.8:

```
cd /usr/lib/apt/methods:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 112808 Sep 13  2017 http
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  92328 Jan 18 11:42 https
```

What is the correct config to use client cert in apt 1.6.6?